# html frames fails when referenced with file:///

Tags: html, frames

I have a large set of html files that I keep on my windows 10 system that I have not used in a long time.  They use frames and I access them using the file:/// mechanism.  These no longer works in firefox or chrome but do work with edge.  I believe this is due to cross origin frame problem referenced here

[SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

The actual error produced is

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null"

I have moved enough of the pages to aws web space to verify that the pages function correctly when retrieved from a web server.

My question is...

Is there any way I can make this work from my local windows 10 system other than adding a web server to it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can make this work from my local windows 10 system other than adding a web server to it?

No.